# How does CrudRepository know which table to get data?

Tags: java, database, http, service, repository

I built an application with Angular, SpringBoot and MySQL Database.
It uses CrudRepository and I don't understand it (everything is working OK).
How does the controllers/repository know which table to get the data from? I mean, I don't specify table name. 
Can someone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend `CrudRepository` you define its generic type. In Here you tell from which `Entity` class the repository will fetch the data. And `Entity` classes in `JPA` are used to represents `Tables`. So thats how it knows from where to get data. for example :

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>  {
}
```

In the code above, I specified the generic type to be `User`, Also `User` is my Entity class which represents `users` table in my `database`. So this Repository will deal with `users` table.

Answer (score 3):

In spring boot data JPA application any model is annotated with either `@Entity` or along with `@Table(name = "User")`. In case of former, the default table name is same as Entity Name.

Also, when you create any repository like:
`public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>` the default implementation of Entity i.e User is referred to perform all operations in generic manner.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following explanation helpful since it goes through all possible combinations of `@Entity` and `@Table` and lists the corresponding query.
https://walkingtechie.blogspot.com/2019/06/difference-between-entity-and-table.html